# ERROR 2024-02-28 14:45:07,856 [WrapperListener_start_runner]

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform

please help me, how to resolve the below issue

```
ERROR 2024-02-28 14:45:07,856 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.launcher.DefaultMuleContainer: 
********************************************************************************
* A Fatal error has occurred while the server was running:                     *
* More than one directory under                                                *
* C:\AnypointStudio\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.5.ee_7.16 *
* .0.202311061606\mule\services\api-gateway-contract-service-1.3.1\META-INF\ma *
* ven\com.mulesoft.anypoint so pom.xml file for artifact in folder             *
* C:\AnypointStudio\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.5.ee_7.16 *
* .0.202311061606\mule\services\api-gateway-contract-service-1.3.1 could not   *
* be found (java.lang.IllegalStateException)                                   *
*                                                                              *
* The error is fatal, the system will shutdown                                 *
********************************************************************************
org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.StartException: Error processing service JAR file
```

Per MuleSoft suggestions, I tried the possible ways, those are not helpfull for me.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Be specific.